# IDE shows error but Jest runs it without any issue

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I have written a unit test in Jest for a TypeScript function(`checkEmail`) that internally calls `showAlert`.

`showAlert` in the `utils.ts`:

```
export const showAlert = (message: string) => {
  toast(message);
};
```

And in my test case I have mocked the above function:

```
import {showAlert} from './utils'

showAlert = jest.fn()
```

[image: Error]

Although the test case works as expected, the IDE(in VSCode and WebStorm) shows error in the test file: `Cannot assign to 'showAlert' because it is not a variable.`

```
showAlert = jest.fn()
^^^^^^^^^
```

Any help to get rid of the above error would be greatly appreciated.

Usage of the `showAlert`:

```
function checkEmail(email: string) {
    if (!email.trim()) {
        showAlert('Email is required.');
    }
}
```

Repo to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/shishiranshuman13/tsjest-demo-error

Comment: Can you show a code where you are using showAlert() ?

Comment: @Vayrex I have updated the description. Please have a look. :)

Comment: I've also faced the same issue. It would be much better if I can find the solution for it. When we use the above pattern, jest is able to mock the function successfully, but the Typescript compiler shows the above error for the mock assignement.

Comment: Try doing this jest.mock('. /utils')

Comment: @VivekN Yep. I have tried that as well. No luck. Please feel free to play around with the above repo.

Comment: After going through the docs, I would say it is working as intended. This is how ES6 modules work, imports are constant and we can not reassign them. Even though the jest is able to mock them, it is fundamentally not correct to reassign the exported member. You can visit this issue for detailed explanation: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6751

Comment: @HardikModha I am using `commonjs` module for the test cases. It's added in the `tsconfig.test.json`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize variables or constants.

UPDATE:

```
describe("Show alert", () => {

  let showAlert: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    showAlert = jest.fn();
  })

  it("must be called once", () => {
    expect(showAlert.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

Here is link to similar issue.  https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936

Comment: I am getting the error in the test file. I cannot share the exact code here.

Comment: I don't get it. How is that a mocked version of the `showAlert` function?

Comment: It is not really show alert, if you want to test calls of some function, your are using just mock function. 
You may have some test case and during it's execution showAlert must be called number of times. So you don't need real fnction. 

If you want to test a function execution and output, you need to have real one not a mock.

Comment: Ok. I think my description was not clear. I have updated it, please have a look again. I am writing a test case for the `checkEmail` function and I want to check if the `showAlert` function is being called or not. Obviously, I cannot use Jest's `toBeCalled` on the actual implementation. So I have to mock the `showAlert` function and check if it's being called or not.

Comment: So basically what I am asking is what's the correct way to mock a module function. I have tried `jest.unmock('./utils', () => {showAlert: jest.fn()})`. This looks very dirty since I have more functions in the utils.ts.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot assign to 'showAlert' because it is not a variable.

Use `import`/`require`:

```
import utils = require('./utils');
utils.showAlert = jest.fn();
```

Comment: With `import/require`, I get this error: `Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript modules. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"', 'import d from "mod"', or another module format instead.`

Comment: Use `module: commonjs`